# Macro To Read Field Names and set to value from other object

Tags: clojure, macros, clojure-java-interop

I am new to clojure and am trying to refactor some code that I've written that looks like this

```
(defn transform
  [entity]
  (let [new-obj (doto (SomeObj.)
                (.setField1 (:field-1 entity)))
  new-obj))
```

I have many objects that will need this implemented but would like to create a macro that accepts an `entity`, `prototype` Ex: `(SomeObj.)`, and a `map` where the keys are the field names of the prototype and the values are vectors of keywords to get the correct field from the `entity`. For each `key` I would need to call .set + keyName using the argument from `(get-in map [value as a vector])`.

My hope is for each new entity I can create a config of the mappings and only write code for special cases. Is this possible using a macro?

Or is there a more idiomatic way to do this in clojure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you could easily do it with a macro like this:

```
(defmacro map-to [type mappings entity]
  `(doto (new ~type)
     ~@(map (fn [[field entity-field]]
              `(~(symbol (str ".set" (clojure.string/capitalize field)))
                (~entity-field ~entity)))
            mappings)))
```

this would generate exactly the code you need:

```
(map-to java.util.Date {date :dt minutes :mm hours :h}
        {:dt 10 :mm 22 :h 12})
```

would be expanded into the following:

```
(doto
  (new java.util.Date)
  (.setDate (:dt {:dt 10, :mm 22, :h 12}))
  (.setMinutes (:mm {:dt 10, :mm 22, :h 12}))
  (.setHours (:h {:dt 10, :mm 22, :h 12})))
```

a few things to notice here:

1) you don't need to introduce a new variable `new-obj`, since `doto` returns the object being operated on.

2) your mappings should be passed as a literal map, because otherwise you cannot get the keys to pass to `.` special form.

3) you can see that the `entity` map is being repeated. You can fix this by introducing another binding inside the macro:

```
(defmacro map-to [type mappings entity]
  (let [ent (gensym "entity")]
    `(let [~ent ~entity]
       (doto (new ~type)
         ~@(map (fn [[field entity-field]]
                  `(~(symbol (str ".set" (clojure.string/capitalize field)))
                    (~entity-field ~ent)))
                mappings)))))
```

so now it expands like this:

```
(let [entity20047 {:dt 10, :mm 22, :h 12}]
  (doto
    (new java.util.Date)
    (.setDate (:dt entity20047))
    (.setMinutes (:mm entity20047))
    (.setHours (:h entity20047))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map-to java.util.Date {date :dt minutes :mm hours :h}
              {:dt 10 :mm 22 :h 12})

;;=> #inst "2016-09-10T09:22:48.867-00:00"

user> (let [ent {:dt 10 :mm 22 :h 12}]
        (map-to java.util.Date {date :dt minutes :mm hours :h} ent))

;;=> #inst "2016-09-10T09:22:48.899-00:00"
```

(the value is three hours earlier due to my time zone (gmt+3))

**update**

to get your desired behaviour (with `get-in`) you can just slightly modify this macro:

```
(defmacro map-to [type mappings entity]
  (let [ent (gensym "entity")]
    `(let [~ent ~entity]
       (doto (new ~type)
         ~@(map (fn [[field entity-field]]
                  `(~(symbol (str ".set" (clojure.string/capitalize field)))
                    (get-in ~ent ~entity-field)))
                mappings)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map-to java.util.Date {date [:date :dt]
                              minutes [:time :mm]
                              hours [:time :h]}
              {:date {:dt 10} :time {:mm 22 :h 12}})

;;=> #inst "2016-09-10T09:22:41.935-00:00"
```

expands to:

```
(let [entity20094 {:date {:dt 10}, :time {:mm 22, :h 12}}]
  (doto
    (new java.util.Date)
    (.setDate (get-in entity20094 [:date :dt]))
    (.setMinutes (get-in entity20094 [:time :mm]))
    (.setHours (get-in entity20094 [:time :h]))))
```

now you can make one more macro to automate the creation of mapping functions:

first of all you need a function to produce maker name from class object:

```
(defn make-name [c]
  (->> c
       .getName
       (#(clojure.string/split % #"\."))
       (clojure.string/join "-")
       (str "create-")
       symbol))

user> (make-name java.util.Date)
;;=> create-java-util-Date
```

now the macro to define functions to create instances from entities:

```
(defmacro defmapper [type mappings]
  `(defn ~(make-name type) [entity#]
     (map-to ~type ~mappings entity#)))
```

this one would create functions, that are, given an entity, convert it to the class instance. It's just an ordinary function:

```
(defmapper java.util.Date {date [:date :dt]
                           minutes [:time :mm]
                           hours [:time :h]})
```

expands to:

```
(defn create-java-util-Date [entity__20122__auto__]
  (map-to
    java.util.Date
    {date [:date :dt], minutes [:time :mm], hours [:time :h]}
    entity__20122__auto__))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map create-java-util-Date
           [{:date {:dt 10} :time {:mm 22 :h 12}}
            {:date {:dt 11} :time {:mm 22 :h 12}}
            {:date {:dt 12} :time {:mm 22 :h 12}}])

;;(#inst "2016-09-10T09:22:18.974-00:00" 
;; #inst "2016-09-11T09:22:18.974-00:00" 
;; #inst "2016-09-12T09:22:18.974-00:00")
```